# selectedrow on hidden boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've done my research here and I can now succesfully get a value of a hidden boundfield column in my gridview. The problem is I can't target the a hidden column of the row that I selected.

can I use `GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;` something like that on a hidden column.Is it possible?

here is my code:

```
   protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = true;
        //stock_id_gridview_1();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string id = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["id"].ToString();

            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT transaction_id,transaction_number 
                               FROM stocks_history
                               WHERE id = @id", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    transaction_id = rdr["transaction_id"].ToString();

                    //lbl_test_id.Text = rdr["transaction_id"].ToString();
                    transaction_number = rdr["transaction_number"].ToString();

                    lbl_test_id.Text = transaction_id + " " + transaction_number;
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                        CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
                        runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="Product Name"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="stock_name" HeaderText="Stock Name"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="stock_id" HeaderText="Stock I.D."
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="stock_in" HeaderText="Stock In"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="stock_out" HeaderText="Stock Out"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="stock_on_hand" HeaderText="On hand"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="max_date" HeaderText="Date & Time"
                                DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt}"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="false" HeaderText="id"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"
                                        Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" HeaderText="Review">
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm"></ControlStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I wanted to target this bound field:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="false" HeaderText="id"
                                SortExpression="DateField" />
```

Comment: What you mean "can't target  the a hidden column of the row that I selected."?

Comment: I was thinking of using `GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;` something like that on a hidden column.Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can take it, but need to use DataKeyNames property. Can you share your html code also?

Comment: @mww yeah I think I did that datakey thing.I didn't understand it well tho.going to update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You use attribute `DataKeyNames`, you can take value from invisible column like

Use Attribute

```
   <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView" DataKeyNames="id">
    </asp:GridView>
```

And you can access the data

```
var id = GridView.DataKeys[RowIndex].Values[KeyIndex]
```

To get selected row hidden column value

```
var id = GridView.DataKeys[GridView.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Values[0];
```

Comment: the hidden value of the row I selected?

Comment: sorry but your code works the same way as mine.I need to selectedrow functionality on a hidden column

Comment: Yes, Your column "id" whith index 7 is invisible so you must add attribute and get it as I show that's all. RowIndex in your case will be row.RowIndex and KeyIndex will be 0, becouse you use one attribute DataKeyNames.

Comment: How could I use it if I selected a hidden column of a specfic row?

Comment: it says `does not contain a definition for CurrentCell`